# Multiple Scopes using OAuth2WebServerFlow

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to authorize multiple scopes using OAuth2WebServerFlow(). Here is my current code:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id=id,
    client_secret=secret,
    scope= ['scope1','scope2','scope3'],
    approval_prompt='force',
    access_type='offline')
```

When I am redirected to Google Authorization screen, the only permissions the app is asking for is to "Have offline access". Additionally, I have those scopes turned on in the API Console.

Comment: Are you actually sending 'scope1' etc., or have you replaced those for this question? It would make sense to post your actual code, in case the problem is in a bit you've redacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scope-param):

> In addition to these OpenID-specific scopes, your scope argument can
>   also include other scope strings. All scope strings must be
>   space-separated. For example, if you wanted per-file access to a
>   user’s Google Drive, your scope might be openid profile email
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file.

So in your case:

```
scope= 'scope1 ' + 'scope2 ' + 'scope3'
```

Example:

```
scope = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write ' +
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction')
```

*EDIT*

As @Greg mentioned:

> OAuth2WebServerFlow takes either a string or an iterable of strings,
>   which it turns into the space-separated parameter before constructing
>   the auth-URL.

I tend to use oAuth for the apis (application authorization) and not that much for a user oauth so I forgot that I had observed this at my own apps as well.

If your scope has **invalid** grants then you will get an error about wrong grants.

Though if you ask for the **correct** grants most of the times they are combined.

In the following example I am asking about `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write ' +
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'`

but though I get prompted only for offline access. 
My application is working fine and permissions are correct. 
The application **does not** have more permissions (other apis).

Comment: OAuth2WebServerFlow takes either a string or an iterable of strings, which it turns into the space-separated parameter before constructing the auth-URL.

Comment: @Greg Nice catch. Didn't know about that. Then the permissions should be correct. I have encountered the same. The scope at the example only requests fro offline permissions and does not show the rest of the scope items.

Comment: I tried both methods and the additional scope are not showing up on the screen, but the application can perform actions based on those scopes. Additionally, the URL that is generated by the flow contains the scopes in it, but it not showing up on the screen.

Comment: @Alex exectelly. See my comment to Greg. They are not showing but the app is OK. At least we both learned something today. Maybe its how it should work but I prefer if all scope where shown

Comment: @Greg I updated the answer. Can you maybe explain with only one "combined" scope is asked? Is this due to the credentials used ? May I suspect that it's due to the user asking the permissions related? Eg the user is already an app admin ?

Comment: @Alex I updated the answer with the things mentioned and my experience. Though I hope as well for a better answer.

Comment: Just to revisit, the problem was actually that the auth screen was just showing new scopes that I was requesting. If I deleted the credentials and made the user step through the oAuth dance again, all scopes that I requested were present. I'll mark it as the answer though. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex thanks as well. Tried your solution by for me still groups some/few of the permissions.